# '+[UIImage didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b6eba078

Tags: ios

Iam using uimageview in tableview, before adding uiimage view in tableview the Application get crash due to this problem ( +[UIImage didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1a0bd1798 ).

Answer (score 0):

**didReceiveMemoryWarning** is UIViewController method, so, suppose, you pass UIImage instance to place, where UIViewController expected

Comment: When reloading UITableview with multiple images didReceiveMemoryWarning this issues appears